# Element must be clicked twice to addClass (custom directive)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

When trying to toggle between a grid and list view for data, our custom directive built to add and remove an `.active` class to the selected `<a>` tag will only add to the list element when the list element is clicked twice. The grid element's class add and remove works fine. I can't figure out where the flaw is coming from since grid and list are built the same. Notice, the grid view has active as default, but I've played around with removing it or setting the list as active by default, and neither affects the issue.

toggle.html:

```
<nav class="layout-toggle">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="goto-grid active" ng-click="gotoGrid()">
                <img src="example"/>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="goto-list" ng-click="gotoList()">
                <img src="example"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

custom directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('appApp')
    .directive('viewToggle', function (analysisFactory) {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'views/directives/toggle.html',
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope:{},
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                scope.gotoGrid = function(){
                    angular.element( element[0].querySelector('.goto-grid') ).addClass('active');
                    angular.element( element[0].querySelector('.goto-list') ).removeClass('active');
                };

                scope.gotoList = function(){
                    angular.element( element[0].querySelector('.goto-grid') ).removeClass('active');
                    angular.element( element[0].querySelector('.goto-list') ).addClass('active');
                };

            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using ng-class for this typical activate/deactivate use case:

```
<nav class="layout-toggle">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a ng-class="{'active' : grid}" class="goto-grid" ng-click="grid=true;list=false">
                <img src="example"/>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a ng-class="{'active' : list}" class="goto-list" ng-click="grid=false;list=true">
                <img src="example"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And you can empty your link function.

Comment: Thanks, but that is still causing the issue of needing to click twice to add the active class to the list `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem happens because you already start up with the `.active` class on your template.

Perhaps a better strategy would be removing all `.active` classes and then adding it only to the one that was clicked.

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.removeAll = function(){
        angular.element( element[0].querySelector('.goto-list') ).removeClass('active');
        angular.element( element[0].querySelector('.goto-grid') ).removeClass('active');
    }
    scope.gotoGrid = function(){
        scope.removeAll();
        angular.element( element[0].querySelector('.goto-grid') ).addClass('active');
    };

    scope.gotoList = function(){
        scope.removeAll();
        angular.element( element[0].querySelector('.goto-list') ).addClass('active');
    };
}
```

Please try that out and let me know. Hope that helps. Keep in mind that this is not a very angularish way to do it though.

Comment: Similar to @cuttlas's answer, this still causing the issue of needing to click twice to add the active class to the list <a> tag.